# PHP mysql select only the rows with highest value (random character numeric order)

Tags: php

Example:

```
thisisline>and>1
thisisanother>line>something>13
just>another>line>143
short>11
```

I have this kind of data in my database on column 'profile'. What I need is to pick columns user_name and profile from the database where profile has the 5 highest values after the last occurance of the '>'

Comment: What's the question? Actually, can you describe the problem better?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to extract the numbers from your lines. Afterwards, order them and take the ones you want.

```
$lines = "thisisline>and>1
thisisanother>line>something>13
just>another>line>143
short>11";

$tmp = explode("\n", $lines); //separate lines

$numbers = array();

foreach($tmp as $line)
{
    $numbers[] = substr($line, strrpos($line, ">") + 1); //extract number
}

rsort($numbers); //order your results

$count = 2; //define the count of results

$result = array_slice($numbers, 0, $count); //just take the ones which you want

var_dump($result);
```

You'll get your result as an array.

Working example [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/311e344fd79a6de283ee5df872e4f3897633c804) in a php sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
$theNumber = substr($string, strrpos($string, ">")+1);
```

This should give you the number for each line. Then, you just compare the numbers.

Comment: Yeah, I fixed it a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this. 
Get all lines into an array, parse them, store the last value in an array, sort it revrse mode, and do what you want.

```
$lines = 'thisisline>and>1
thisisanother>line>something>13
just>another>line>143
short>11';

define('NUM_TO_GET', 2); //Get the two highest. Rewrite it to 5!
$array = explode("\n", $lines);
$results = array();
foreach ($array as $line) {
    $tmp = explode('>', $line);
    $results [] = $tmp[count($tmp) - 1];
}
rsort($results);
for ($i = 0; $i < NUM_TO_GET; $i++) {
    if (isset($results[$i])) {
        echo $results[$i] . "<br />";
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```